Web URL value in Power BI to locate a specific cell in Excel Online
Can someone please help me figure out how to redirect to a specific value in an Excel data source from a table matrix visual?
To explain further, I've attached the table I have in Power BI. What I want to achieve is that when I click on a Serial Number, it will redirect to the online Excel file and highlight the specific cell value.
The default URL for my Excel template doesn't redirect to the specific value I selected; instead, it randomly opens a sheet.

